# how to restrict data loading while click on tabs in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have 2 tabs in my application and i am getting all datas in API response. So at first time itself my all datas are getting loaded.

My two tabs are

- tab 1
- tab 2

So by default always it is in tab 1. So I want to load only tab 1 data and i do not want to load tab 2 datas. After click on tab 2 only i need to load the tab 2 datas and that time i don't want to load the tab 1 datas.

- I have a flag called "isfirst". If "isfirst" is "1", then i need to load only the first tab content. Same as if "isfirst" is "0", then i need to load only the second tab content.
- It is for performance improvement. If I click on second tab, the first tab existing data should not get load again. and if i click first tab again i need to destroy the second tab datas.

Please look at the plunkr,

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5Ng9PHkrluKUSzQhor34?p=preview&preview)

```js
[
 {
 "fruit":[
  {"Apple":"Apple content goes here", "isfirst":"1"},
  {"Pear":"Pear content goes here", "isfirst":"0"}
]
}
   ]
```

```js
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var TabsDemoCtrl = function ($scope,$http, $timeout) {
  $scope.tabs = [
    { title:"Apple", content:[] , isLoaded:false , active:true},
    {  title:"Pear", content:[] , isLoaded:false }
  ];
  
  

  
  $scope.getContent=function(index){
    /* see if we have data already */
    if($scope.tabs.isLoaded){
      return
    }
    /* or make request for data delayed to show Loading... */
    $timeout(function(){
        var jsonFile='data1.json'
            $http.get(jsonFile).then(function(res){
            $scope.tabs.content=res.data[0].fruit;
            console.log(res.data[0].fruit);
            $scope.tabs.isLoaded=true;
        });
    
    },100)
  
  }
  
  
  
};
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
  

  <tabset>
   
    
  <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" select="getContent($index)" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">
  <div ng-hide="!tabs.isLoaded">
  <h1>{{tab.title}}</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="item in tabs.content">
      <p>{{item[tab.title]}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-hide="tabs.isLoaded"><h3>Loading...</h3></div>
  </tab>
    
    
  </tabset>

  <hr />

</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here how to restrict loading datas using angularjs. Based on the tab click i want to load the datas dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

But you have only one json file. If you want to load tabs data separately then you need to have at least 2 different json files (for both tabs accordingly). But for now you have the same json file which loaded for both tabs. For example if you will have 2 json files:

`data_1.json`

```html
{
  "title": "Pear",
  "desc": "Pear content goes here"
}
```

`data_2.json`

```html
{
  "title": "Apple",
  "desc": "Apple content goes here"
}
```

then your code will look like:

`index.html`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
  

  <tabset>
   
    
  <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" select="getContent($index)" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">
  <div ng-hide="!tab.isLoaded">
  <h1>{{tab.content.title}}</h1>
  <p>{{tab.content.desc}}</p>
  </div>
  <div ng-hide="tab.isLoaded"><h3>Loading...</h3></div>
  </tab>
    
    
  </tabset>

  <hr />

</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`example.js`

```js
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var TabsDemoCtrl = function ($scope,$http, $timeout) {
  $scope.tabs = [
    { title:"Apple", content:[] , isLoaded:false , active:true},
    {  title:"Pear", content:[] , isLoaded:false }
  ];
  
  

  
  $scope.getContent=function(index){
    /* see if we have data already */
    if($scope.tabs[index].isLoaded){
      return
    }
    /* or make request for data delayed to show Loading... */
    $timeout(function(){
        var jsonFile='data_'+ index +'.json'
            $http.get(jsonFile).then(function(res){
            $scope.tabs[index].content = res.data;
            $scope.tabs[index].isLoaded=true;
        });
    
    },100)
  
  }
  
  
  
};
```

Comment: but i have only one json.

Comment: The general issue that you're trying to assign your json data to array `$scope.tabs.content`, instead of that you need to assign it to appropriate object, for example `$scope.tabs[index].content`

Comment: Please accept the answer for stack overflow community if you think its answered.